# Apresentar dados de uma tabela somando uma coluna específica

Tags: php, mysqli

boa tarde!

Sou iniciante em php e estou tentando construir uma tabela que informe a data e a soma de vendas realizadas, no entanto, só consigo apresentar a soma dos valores mas não consigo apresentar a data referida... segue o cód.

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi( 'localhost', 'login', 'senha', 'db' );
$q_soma= ('SELECT SUM(valor) AS resultado FROM vendas GROUP BY data');

if ($result = $mysqli->query($q_soma)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s <br />", $row["resultado"]);
    }
    $result->close();
};
```

Comment: Precisa colocar o campo de data na lista de campos e depois imprimir como fez com `resultado`

Answer (score 0):

> $q_soma= ('SELECT SUM(valor) AS resultado FROM vendas GROUP BY data');

Troque para:

> $q_soma= ('SELECT SUM(valor) AS resultado, **data** FROM vendas GROUP BY data');

Com todas as alterações feitas, fica com algo assim:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi( 'localhost', 'login', 'senha', 'db' );
$q_soma= ('SELECT SUM(valor) AS resultado FROM vendas GROUP BY data');

if ($result = $mysqli->query($q_soma)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print "vendas: {$row['resultado']} - {$row['data']}";
    }
    $result->close();
};
```